# Календарь jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Я подключил в календарь, в файле myscript.js прописал

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
    });
  });
```

При нажатии в поле открывается календарь. При выборе даты, поле выбирается, а сам календарь при этом остается будто бы число не выбрали и лишь потом поле заполняется датой. Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем причина?

---

**Обновление из комментариев**

Порядок подключения такой:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/allscripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```

Где здесь может быть неправильно подключение?

Если написать то, что в верхней части [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/320560/13336):

> ```
> $("#date").datepicker({
>     showOtherMonths: true,
>     selectOtherMonths: true,
>     /* Кликнули на дату в календаре */
>     onChange: function(formated, dates){
>         /* Передаем выбранную дату в наш input */
>         $("#date").val(formated);
>         /* Прячем календарь */
>         $("#date").DatePickerHide();
>     }
> });
> ```

то ничего не отображается в поле.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, вам нужно это:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    /* Кликнули на дату в календаре */
    onChange: function(formated, dates){
        /* Передаем выбранную дату в наш input */
        $("#date").val(formated);
        /* Прячем календарь */
        $("#date").DatePickerHide();
    }
});
```

**Update**: перепутал datepicker'ы...
**[По умолчанию DatePicker скрывается, при выборе даты (кликни)](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/x3wAe/)**
Проверяйте правильность подключения стилей, скриптов и тому подобного.
Вот полный код странички с рабочим вариантом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Demo Page</title>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js'></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- Подключаем DatePicker -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#date").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="date" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я всю информацию перенес в вопрос. Комментарии можно удалять.